# How can I modify an struct in another .c?

Tags: c

I'm trying to add some data to my struct in another .c, but I'm getting segfault.

This is an example of my main.c.
I used "REGISTER *reg" to use the struct from the other file.

```
#include "otherfile.c"

int main(){
   char mom[30];
   char baby[30];
   int age;

   REGISTER *reg;

   scanf("%s", mom);
   scanf("%s", baby);
   scanf("%d", &age);

   set_mothersName(reg,mom);
   set_childsName(reg,baby);
   set_age(reg,age);

return 0;
}
```

In the other file, I try this:

```
typedef struct register{
   char mothersName[30];
   char childsName[30];
   int age;
}REGISTER;

void set_mothersName(REGISTER *reg, char* name){
   strcpy(reg->mothersName,name);
}
void set_childsName(REGISTER *reg, char*name){
   strcpy(reg->childsName,name);
}
void set_age(REGISTER* reg, int age){
   reg->age = age;
}
```

I think I'm using pointers wrong, but I can't know where and why.

Comment: `REGISTER *reg;` is an uninitialized pointer - it doesn't point to a valid `REGISTER` object

Comment: So to inicialize it, do I have to use dynamic allocation?

Comment: In this case you could simply declare it as `REGISTER reg;` and pass `&reg` as argument to your functions

Comment: @UnholySheep But then it gets "error: storage size of 'reg' isn't know"

Comment: In that case you haven't included the file you claim you did. Please create a real [mcve]

Comment: You should not include a `.c` file containing definitions.

Comment: @Gerhardh  should I define this in the ' .h' file?

Comment: You should only put declarations in headers. Definitions should go to separate C files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the others answers stated, you have an issue with a **uninitialized pointer**. It also just so happens that **register is a C keyword**, so you might want to change your lowercase register to something like s_register to avoid confusions and probably compiling errors.
Since you seem to be learning about pointers I will go a bit more in depth in my explanation.

When declaring a `REGISTER *reg;` you declare a pointer, of size 8 which will contain an address to a space you have manually assigned. By default pointers are **not initialized** so you basically have a pointer to a random place in memory.

When declaring a `REGISTER reg;`, you are declaring a variable of size 64 (size of your structure) on the stack with its space assigned like you would declare a char (size 1). When using the `&` symbol, you access to the address of this structure, the pointer to this allocated space.

I rewrote your code adding a .h file to declare your functions because I was getting compiling errors trying  yours, the compiler found multiple declarations for your functions.

Here is the code :

file.c :

```
    #include "declar.h"
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
       char mom[30];
       char baby[30];
       int age;

       REGISTER reg;

       scanf("%s", mom);
       scanf("%s", baby);
       scanf("%d", &age);

       set_mothersName(&reg, mom);
       set_childsName(&reg, baby);
       set_age(&reg, age);

       return 0;
    }
```

otherfile.c :

```
    #include "declar.h"
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdio.h>

    void set_mothersName(REGISTER *reg, char *name)
    {
       strcpy(reg->mothersName, name);
    }
    void set_childsName(REGISTER *reg, char *name)
    {
       strcpy(reg->childsName, name);
    }
    void set_age(REGISTER *reg, int age)
    {
       reg->age = age;
    }
```

declar.h :

```
    #ifndef DECLAR_H_
    # define DECLAR_H_

    typedef struct reg
    {
       char mothersName[30];
       char childsName[30];
       int age;
    } REGISTER;

    void set_mothersName(REGISTER *reg, char *name);
    void set_childsName(REGISTER *reg, char *name);
    void set_age(REGISTER *reg, int age);

    #endif
```

Let me know if this works out for you, also be careful with a use of scanf in real word applications, it is very easy to break by simply overflowing the buffer.
Hopefully this helped you :)

Comment: I was defining the struct 'REGISTER' in the 'otherfile.c'. Now it works!

Answer (score 0):

As user unholy Sheep says "`REGISTER *reg;` is an uninitialized pointer - it doesn't point to a valid `REGISTER` object."

Instead of declaring `REGISTER *reg;`, just declare as

```
REGISTER reg;
```

and now call the functions as for example:

```
set_mothersName(&reg,mom);
```